# C++ how to choose a random variable from a vector list?

Tags: c++, vector, random

Im trying to create a function that randomly selects a customers Name from a vector List. Below is my attempt at this function using the mt19937 engine

```
Carly:Cat:ABCCCCE.
Dodgy Dan:Dog:BCACECC.
Ernie:Ettin:AABCCDD.
Sally:Snake:AEEEEEE.
```

for example, above is the contents of the vector list. If working the function has a possibility to return either Carly, Dodgy Dan, Ernine or Sally randomly(the customers name).

```
struct Customer {
    std::string customerName;
};

float randomCus(const vector<Customer>& customerList,const Builder& b) {

float total;
std::random_device random_device;
std::mt19937 engine{random_device()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, customerList.size() - 1);

for(Customer x:customerList) {
for(int i=0; i < customerList.size(); i++){

int random_element = x.customerName[dist(engine)];
cout << random_element <<  "This is a random customer name: ";
}
return total;
}
```

An expected output could include

```
Carly was randomlly selected
Dodgy Dan was randomlly selected
```

Comment: you are picking a random character from each `customerName`. You want to pick a random element of `customerList` instead

Answer (score 0):

You are accesing a random char of the coustomer name.

```
void randomCus(const vector<Customer>& customerList,const Builder& b) {

std::random_device random_device;
std::mt19937 engine{random_device()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, customerList.size() - 1);

int random_index = dist(engine);
std::cout << "This is a random customer name: " << customerList[random_index].customerName;

}
```

This prints one random name each time the function gets called.

edit: missing member call && Typo

Comment: this gets an error on line 7 "no suitable conversion function from "lambda []auto ()->auto" to "int" exists" and line 8 for the last << "no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << const Customer"

Comment: @DavidLing shoul be fixed now. forgot to acces the string member.

Comment: its not liking this line int random_index = dist(engine)];

Comment: this does complie and run, however it keeps returning the same name.

Comment: is it posible to seed this?

Comment: i Dont know how the random engine works, but is posible: https://diego.assencio.com/?index=6890b8c50169ef45b74db135063c227c

Comment: would you know why its not randomizing? the code you've provided that is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211863/discussion-between-vvalter-bach-and-david-ling).